# Why is the Apostle icon a shoe with wings?

Tags: civilization-6

The unit icon for Apostles looks like some kind of weird shoe with wings.

[image: Apostle unit icon]

Why is it so? It's the only unit in the game whose icon I couldn't grasp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The emblem is based on the [Talaria](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talaria), a symbol of the Greek messenger got Hermes. It also stands for traveling quickly over great distances.

In this case, as is backed by the [Civilization 6 wiki](http://civilization.wikia.com/wiki/Apostle_(Civ6)), the shoes go along with the literal interpretation of the Apostle, acting as a messenger and ambassador for the chosen deity of a given religion as Hermes was known for doing and needing to travel far in order to do so.